# How to trace error with counter in do while loop in C++?

Tags: c++, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to get i to read array with numbers and get the smaller number, store it in variable and then compare it with another variable that is again from two other numbers (like 2,-3).

There is something wrong in the way I implement the do while loop. I need the counter 'i' to be updated twice so it goes through I have 2 new variables from 4 compared numbers. When I hard code it n-1,n-2 it works but with the loop it gets stuck at one value.

```
int i=0;
        int closestDistance=0;
        int distance=0;
        int nextDistance=0;
        do
        {
            distance = std::min(values[n],values[n-i]);  //returns the largest
            distance=abs(distance);
            i++;
            nextDistance=std::min(values[n],values[n-i]);
            nextDistance=abs(closestDistance); //make it positive then comp
            if(distance<nextDistance)
                closestDistance=distance;//+temp;
            else
                closestDistance=nextDistance;
            i++;
        }
        while(i<n);
        return closestDistance;
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do in following lines.
`nextDistance=std::min(values[n],values[n-i]);
nextDistance=abs(closestDistance); //make it positive , then computed`

Comment: values[n] accepts arguments from an array(it should). If the array is {2,-1,3,6} it should take 2 and -1 , take the abs val of -1 and compute result. It works when I code as values[n-1],values[n-2]  and values[n-3] ...I know it looks so stupid but when I tried with loop it didn't work.

Comment: in the first line you have received the min(values[n],values[n-i]) in nextDistance variable, but without using it anywhere , you have again assigned  abs(closestDistance) to nextDistance..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
int i = 0;
int m = 0;
do{
  int lMin = std::min(values[i],values[i + 1]);
  i += 2;
  int rMin = std::min(values[i], values[i + 1]);
  m = std::min(lMin,rMin);
  i += 2;
}while(i < n);
return m;
```

I didn't understand what you meant, but this compares values in `values` 4 at a time to find the minimal. Is that all you needed?

Note that if `n` is the size of values, this would go out of bounds. `n` would have to be the size minus 4, leading to odd exceptional cases.

The issue with your may be in the call to `abs`. Are all the values positive? Are you trying to find the smallest absolute value?

Also, note that using `i += 2` twice ensures that you do not repeat any values. This means that you will go over 4 unique values. Your code goes through 3 in each iteration of the loop.

I hope this clarified.

Comment: m = std::min(lMin,rMin); Of course! how didn't i think of this. Thanks!